# Unexpected end of JSON input on seemingly correct JSON input

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I'm making a discord bot and I have this section of code:

```
function addMoney(id, amount){
accounts = fs.readFileSync("accounts.data", 'utf8');
console.log(JSON.parse(accounts))
var obj = JSON.parse(accounts);
var i;
for (i in obj.users){
    if (obj.users[i].id === id){
        obj.users[i].money = obj.users[i].money + amount
        accounts = JSON.stringify(obj);
        writeToFile()
    }
}
return;
```

This is the output console.log is returning:

```
{
  users: [
    { id: 'REMOVED', money: 661, deaths: 1, banned: 0 },
    { id: 'REMOVED', money: 3828, deaths: 1, banned: 0 },
    { id: 'REMOVED', money: 0, deaths: 0, banned: 0 },
    { id: 'REMOVED', money: 940000000, deaths: 0, banned: 0 },
    { id: 'REMOVED', money: 394, deaths: 0, banned: 0 },
    { id: 'REMOVED', money: 10109, deaths: 1, banned: 0 }
  ]
}
```

Aside from it looking strange in a few places, it seems like it should be a perfectly valid JSON, although when I run this script it returns

```
Uncaught Promise Error:  SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at addMoney (/home/bumpjammy/bot/index.js:244:17)
    at transferMoney (/home/bumpjammy/bot/index.js:306:5)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

What makes this even stranger is that it works on my PC, but not anywhere else. This makes me think it is something to do with the machine and not the code itself. I have tried re-installing dependencies, any ideas?

Comment: Do other machines have the `account.data` file?

Comment: They do have the account.data file, yes. This is what you're seeing in the output.

Comment: Can you share the full stacktrace of the error?

Comment: `Uncaught Promise Error:  SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at addMoney (/home/bumpjammy/bot/index.js:244:22)
    at transferMoney (/home/bumpjammy/bot/index.js:307:5)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)`

Comment: Your output does not really look like its coming from `console.log(JSON.parse(accounts))` because console.log, typically doesn't do any indentiation ...

Comment: I don't know if this is what you mean, I'm new to stack overflow as you can see. Hopefully, this is correct.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the stack trace.

Comment: derpirscher, I removed that line of code and the json output did not appear, so I think it is the console.log

Comment: I saw a typo in last item.  `id: '4REMOVED',`

Comment: If that output is the content of `account.data` then the error is expected. That is not valid json, that can be parsed by `JSON.parse`. In JSON, each property name has to be enclosed in quotes, and also you must use double quotes `"` instead of single quotes `'` Please add the content of `account.data` exactly as it is in the file

Comment: derpirscher, now that I look at it, you're correct. I'll look now into why it doesn't have quotes around the property names since the file does.

Comment: OK, now as you have updated the output, it seems more like an output from console.log(). But that would not make any sense, because, if it outputs something, it won't throw an error ... I suspect something completely different: I think you are calling this `addMoney` function multiple times, but your `writeToFile()` isn't using `writeFileSync` so, when you call `addMoney` the second time, it tries to read the file, but writing isn't finished yet, so the json is imcomplete ...

Comment: derpirscher, I've checked the output on my PC and it also doesn't have quotes around the keys. Also, that also confuses me since the 244th line refers to the console.log line, which seems to run fine since it returns the same thing as on my PC.

Comment: This was exactly it! Turns out I was using writeFile instead of writeFileSync. Thank you! I'm new to this, is there a way I can make that comment the answer, or is it something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered by: derpirscher

In the function `writeToFile()` I was using the function `writeFile`. This meant that it didn't sync with other read/write functions. I changed this to `writeFileSync()` and it worked perfectly.